# Uploading a CSV file to S3 Bucket from JSON data

Tags: javascript, mongodb, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, graphql

I am using node js, I am trying to upload a CSV file to the Amazon S3 Bucket and it should give me the url of csv in response.
I have the JSON data in below format :-

```
["a","b","c","d"]
```

How can I ahieve the same ?

Comment: i'm beginner for uploading a file to the aws

Comment: So that we are on the same page, you have a file you would like to upload to AWS S3 service right?

Comment: yes exotically but first i have to call an API and all this work will be done at API level i just need file url

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use AWS for this and code like you can write your needed data in a file in  test.csv because we have permission to write on tmp folder. We use package 'fs' for file write and read.

```
    let csvContent '';
    neededData.forEach((rowArray) =>  {
        const row = Object.values(rowArray);
        csvContent += `${row}\r\n`;
    });
    const tempFileName = `/tmp/test.csv`;
    fs.writeFileSync(tempFileName, csvContent);
    AWS.config.update({ accessKeyId: '....',secretAccessKey'....' });
    return await uploadFile(tempFileName);
```

There we make a function `uploadFile` method:

```
async function uploadFile(filePath) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        fs.readFile(filePath, (err, datauser) => {
            if (err) reject(err);

            const base64data = new Buffer(datauser, 'binary');
            const fileName = 'filename';
            const bucketName = 'bucket name';
            const rigion = 'rigion';
            link = `https://s3-${rigion}.amazonaws.com/${bucketName}/${fileName}`;
            const s3 = new AWS.S3();
            s3.putObject({
                Bucket: bucketName,
                Key: fileName,
                Body: base64data,
                ACL: 'public-read',
            }, () => {
                resolve(link);
            });
        });
    });
}
```

This function will push file on AWS and return URL.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using Javascript you might look at AWS Amplify's Storage component: https://github.com/aws/aws-amplify/blob/master/media/storage_guide.md

For your use case it would be something like:

```
Storage.put('userfile.csv', 'User XXX CSV uploading')
    .then (result => console.log(result))
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
```

Comment: How would you expect this to work? Where are you telling Storage.put() what content/file to use?